# Efficient solution for real-time updating a growing list of thousands of stocks

Tags: database, algorithm, asynchronous, architecture, devops

We have a program that gathers information about stocks through third party API calls, and collects this information and presents it back to the user in a table.

Our program needs to have up to date information at any given moment for every stock in our system ideally. Our program finds new stocks every day, which also have to be continuously updated in real-time.

The current strategy is to deploy numerous instances of a "updater" program. Each instance takes on a subset of the stocks, for example instance A updates all stocks that start with A - M, and instance B updates all stocks that start with N - Z. These instances are kept running, however to scale we need to keep adding instances and still some stocks don't get updated as predictably as we'd like.

Any other suggestions/ideas? Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear from your question why you need multiple instances. Thousands of things updating should not tax a single computer unless there's something you've omitted.

Comment: Are you retrieving only one stock at once with your API? Or a whole list?